# Условие php два условия

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает условие. Данные идут из формы. Показывает одинаковый результат при разных значениях.

```
      if ($proba = 585 and $brand = 1) {
            $price = 108;
        }elseif ($proba = 585 and $brand = 2){
            $price = 100
        }
echo $price;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не `=`, а `==`.

*(еще 17 символов)*